# Python requests 400 error with json

Tags: python, json

I am using the following code in order to register a user in API endpoint:

```
import argparse
import requests
import ConfigParser
import json
import sys
import logging
#from collections import OrderedDict
#from cs-check-user.py import get

# Configuration Parameters
env = 'Pre_internal'

Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.read("../etc/config.ini")
endpoint = Config.get(env, 'endpoint')
admin_user = Config.get(env, 'admin_user')
admin_password = Config.get(env, 'admin_password')

# Logging Config
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s',
                    filename='../logs/create_user.log')

# Functions
def post(login, email, password):
        login_ok = login.lower()

    #data = OrderedDict([('login',login_ok), 
    #                      ('email', email), 
    #                      ('password', password)])
    #data_ok = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=False)
    #data = '{"login": login, "email": email, "password": password}'
    #create_user = requests.post(endpoint, data, auth=(admin_user, admin_password))

        data = {"login": login_ok, "email": email, "password": password}
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        create_user = requests.post(endpoint, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, auth=(admin_user, admin_password))

    if create_user.status_code == 202:
        print 'User has been created successfully'
        logging.info('User has been created successfully %s', login_ok)
        sys.exit(0)

    else:
        print 'Error Received: ', create_user
        logging.error('Received error when creating the user %s %s', login_ok, create_user)
        sys.exit(1)

# Main
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description='''Script to create users in Cloud Storage''', epilog='''Example: ./cs-create-user.py -l dsmc -e dsmc@tid.es -p changeme''' )

parser.add_argument('-l', '--login', help='Login account')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--email', help='Email account')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', help='Password account')
args = parser.parse_args()

if not args.login:
        print 'Login incomplete'
if not args.password:
        print 'Password incomplete'
if not args.email:
        print 'Email incomplete'
else:
    # Check user
    #try:
    #   get(args.login)
    #except SystemExit as exc:
    #   if exc.code == 0:
    #       print 'The user already exists, please select another login.'
    #       sys.exit(1)
    #   else:
            post(args.login, args.password, args.email)
    #
    #   post(args.login, args.password, args.email)
sys.exit(0)
```

After three hours i don't know why i received 400 all time!!! I think that the problem is related to json format, but why?

Please help me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What's the endpoint? Does it have API docs we can view?

Comment: Sorry but is a private endpoint that i have no documentation. I use the following curl to create the users avoid python:
---
curl -v -u aa:bb -X POST http://ip:port/api/customer/ -H "Accept: application/json; version=0" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{ "login": "login", "password": "ejemplo", "email":"ejemplo@mail.com" }'

Answer (score 0):

I debugged this with the help of https://httpbin.org/. First I copied your curl command to send there:

```
curl -v -u aa:bb -X POST httpbin.org/post -H "Accept: application/json; version=0" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"login": "username", "password": "secret", "email":"my_email"}'
```

It returned:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"login\": \"username\", \"password\": \"secret\", \"email\":\"my_email\"}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json; version=0", 
    "Authorization": "Basic YWE6YmI=", 
    "Content-Length": "63", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.43.0"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "email": "my_email", 
    "login": "username", 
    "password": "secret"
  }, 
  "origin": "197.155.4.24", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Then I modified your code to send the equivalent request to the same place, after passing the arguments via argparse. The response looked similar. I compared the two with PyCharm's 'Compare with Clipboard' feature (though any diff tool would do) and the problem became clear:

[image: The difference]

You swapped around password and email in your code! I'm so sorry.

Comment: Hello again, in your code you don't use variables, i think that my problem is related variables and json, please, could you write an example with that? Thank you very much for all.

Comment: @JoséLuis the only 'code' I posted is the curl command. The rest is data. I'm saying that your code is probably fine but you mixed up the password and email arguments, i.e. you have `post(args.login, args.password, args.email)` but also `def post(login, email, password)`. The rest of the post is just showing how I figured it out because I think the technique is interesting and worth knowing about.

Comment: @ Alex, Thank you very much, yes now!!!!!! Was a silly problem that i did not see! Httpbin is a good tool i didn't know it!